# DLL File Being Used by another process in VS 2012 Report Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 installation with Update 5 and I am getting the following error when I try to preview a report:

> The process cannot access the file C:\Users\my user
>   name\AppData\Local\Temp\expression_host_d99c3faa84024586ba8092448e2733d7.dll
>   because it is being used by another process

Note that the dll file name changes each time I try to preview the report.  The expression_host_ portion is static but the rest of the file name seems to be randomly generated.

This error shows up on all my reports in several different solutions.

I have no other applications running so I'm at a loss on what may be using this file.  I searched the web and found several posts but none specific to Visual Studio 2012 and a Reporting project so I'm looking for some troubleshooting advise.

I have tried the following but the error remains:

- Restarting the PC
- Repairing the Update 5
- Shutting down other various processes via the task manager
- Checking in the solution to TFS and checking it back out
- Removing update 5 and installing update 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article identifies the problem and outlines the solutions:

[AB Blogspot](http://alsaydi.blogspot.com/2011/07/report-rendering-fails-in-local-mode.html)

Comment: That article tells about antivirus programs blocking the auto generated dll files. But the question above refers to accessing the dlls by multiple processes at once.